Pine script misses crossovers
The following Pine script misses some crossovers in August and September 2024.
The histogram of the MACD 'delta' clearly shows the crossovers and I have even multiplied the delta by 1000.0 to no avail.  The time interval is 1 day (i.e. price tick interval). What is the reason for this or is this a Pine script bug?
//@version=6
strategy('MACD Strategy2', overlay=false, pyramiding = 4, currency=currency.USD, initial_capital=10000, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0)

fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)
MACD = ta.ema(close, fastLength) - ta.ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ta.ema(MACD, MACDLength)
delta = 10 * (MACD - aMACD)

// Calculate start/end trading dates and time condition
startDate = input.time(timestamp('2024-01-01T00:00:00'))
finishDate = timenow
time_cond = time >= startDate and time <= finishDate
isLastTradingDay = ((timenow-time)<300000000)  // 3.45 days in

// Plots
plot(0, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=1, title='MidLine')
plot(MACD, color=color.new(color.green, 0), linewidth=2, title='MACD', style=plot.style_line)
plot(delta, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), linewidth=2, title='MACDHisto', style=plot.style_histogram)
plot(aMACD, color=color.new(color.maroon, 0), linewidth=2, title='MACDSignal')

// Trades
if ta.crossover(100*delta, 0) and time_cond
    strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")
if ta.crossunder(100*delta, 0) and time_cond
    strategy.close("MacdLE", comment="MacdLE")



The reason for this is your margin settings. It thinks you don't have enough funds to enter a trade whereas you actually have enough capital. This seems a bug to me. I will report this to the development team.
As a workaround, you can change your margin % to zero.
